# Knowing when a View in a ListView has gone off the screen?

Tags: android, image, listview, asynchronous

I have Googled this but can't find an answer, so here goes...

I have a ListView that displays some text and an image. The underlying adapter recycles the views for performance reasons (as per the recommended approach), and I load the images using an AsynchTask as per the recommendation found [on the Android Developers site's bitmap page](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Everything works perfectly and smoothly, but I have one issue. When the View in the adapter is recycled, it still has a reference to the old image (ImageView). If the user scrolls slowly, then the AsynchTask has enough time to load the new image and display it, so there is no visible reloading of the new image to the user.

However, if the user scrolls very quickly, the delay in loading the image means they see the old image (that was loaded when the View was being used by another item) before its replaced by the new image.

So, my question is, how can I detect when a View is no longer visible on the screen, so I can then remove the image? This would mean the user sees an empty list view item that will eventually be loaded with the appropriate image, which would look better.

Many thanks in advance. Here is the list view adapter code.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    ListViewHolder viewHolder;

    // if this is not a recycled view then create a new view for the data...
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.target_list_view_layout, null, true);

        viewHolder = new ListViewHolder();

        viewHolder.manufacturer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer);
        viewHolder.targetName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.targetName);
        viewHolder.targetThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.targetThumbnail);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else
    {
        viewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    TargetDescriptor targetDescriptor = this.selectedTargets.get(position);

    viewHolder.manufacturer.setText(targetDescriptor.manufacturer);
    viewHolder.targetName.setText(targetDescriptor.targetName);

    // At this point I pass the image view reference to my background task to load the image
    LoadImageViewAsynchTask loadImageTask = new LoadImageViewAsynchTask(viewHolder.targetThumbnail, targetDescriptor);
    loadImageTask.execute(new Integer[]
    { 64, 64 });

    return view;
}
```

EDIT: Those that use the eBay Android App can see the effect I am looking for if that helps.

Comment: check ListView listeners, you will find the answer

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't believe how stupid I have been, this is a really easy one liner to solve!

Basically in my adapter if the view is being re-cycled, I simply need to null the ImageView bitmap before the view is re-used. That means the image in the list view item is blank before the next image is loaded. I no longer have the issue of the old image being there whilst the new image is being loaded in the background.

I have also made a change in the adapter that cancels any current AsynchTask bound to the view that might still be loading a previous image that is no longer needed. This was very prevalent when I scroll very fast through the list view, with often two or more image loads backing up, so the image would change several times before settling on the correct image.

Here is the new code, with the changes commented so you can see what is happening:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ListViewHolder viewHolder;

    // if this is not a recycled view then create a new view for the data...
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.target_list_view_layout, null, true);

        viewHolder = new ListViewHolder();

        viewHolder.manufacturer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer);
        viewHolder.targetName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.targetName);
        viewHolder.targetThumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.targetThumbnail);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else
    {
        viewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        // Cancel the previous attempt to load an image as this is going to be superceded by the next image
        viewHolder.loadImageViewAsynchTask.cancel(true);

        // Clear down the old image so when this view is displayed, the user does not see the old image before the
        // new image has a chance to load in the background
        viewHolder.targetThumbnail.setImageBitmap(null);
    }

    TargetDescriptor targetDescriptor = this.selectedTargets.get(position);

    viewHolder.manufacturer.setText(targetDescriptor.manufacturer);
    viewHolder.targetName.setText(targetDescriptor.targetName);

    LoadImageViewAsynchTask loadImageViewAsynchTask = new LoadImageViewAsynchTask(viewHolder.targetThumbnail);
    loadImageViewAsynchTask.setTargetDescriptor(targetDescriptor);
    loadImageViewAsynchTask.execute(new Integer[]
    { 64, 64 });

    // Keep a reference to the task so we can cancel it if the view is recycled next time round to prevent
    // un-neccessary image loads that are out of date
    viewHolder.loadImageViewAsynchTask = loadImageViewAsynchTask;

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Resetting the row to default values did the trick for me. Thanks, it helped.

Comment: @Justin Phillips : How did you cancel the async tasks that were running from the previous views?

Comment: @Ashwin I call the cancel method for views that are being recycled. You can see it in the code listing above.

Answer (score 28):

There is actually a simpler way to do that, you can use a listener :

```
mListView.setRecyclerListener(new AbsListView.RecyclerListener() {
@Override
    public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
  }
});
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer for the question "Knowing when a View in a ListView has gone off the screen?" but it looks like the original author really just needed to know when a view is being recycled.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a LruCache for the bitmaps and have each view in the listview keep the key to the LruCache item, you can control it better..  Then, in getView, you first try and get the bitmap from the LruCache and only download it again if it is not there.

Also, you can set an setOnScrollListener() on the ListView, and use its visibleItemCount parameter to adjust the size of the LruCache the first time the user scrolls.

Comment: The problem with holding the images in a cache is that I get OutOfMemory exceptions. So I have a weak reference to the ImageView that is loaded by the AsynchTask that allows it to be GC'ed.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using overrided `getView` method for display images so you can check convertView. if it was null then you can found that it recycled or it is not initialized before. 
simply like this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder viewholder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewholder = new ViewHolder();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
        viewholder.tvID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvID);
        viewholder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        viewholder.tvFamily = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFamily);
        viewholder.ivMain = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivMain);
    } else {
        viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewholder.tvID.setText(IDs[position]);
    viewholder.tvName.setText(Names[position]);
    viewholder.tvFamily.setText(Familys[position]);
    viewholder.ivMain.setImageResource(Images[position]);
    convertView.setTag(viewholder);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand how the recycling works, except I am loading the image in a background thread using an AsynchTask. So instead of setting the ImageView in my "viewHolder" object (as per your example), I am firing off an AsynchTask at this point in the adapter that takes the ImageView reference and sets the image. I will update my original question with the adapter code so its clearer what I am trying to do.

Comment: Then you can put some icon (like an image holder icon) into the view to display until the asynctask is done.

Comment: @RickFalck Thanks, but this is not the problem I am trying to solve. I need to identify the views that have are no longer physically being displayed so I can clear their images. I could at that point do as you suggested and add a place holder image, or just blank the image view.