# Detect when view is removed from Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I have a custom class that is used as a `View` for each item in a `ListView`. When the `View` initializes, it starts updating itself every second.

Where can I detect that the view is being removed, and cancel the timer?

**Edit**: Here's the code for the view.

```
public class CustomViewCell extends LinearLayout {

    private static final String TAG = "CustomViewCell";

    private ImageView itemImage;
    private TextView itemTitle;
    private TextView itemEstimate;
    private CustomEvent event;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public CustomViewCell(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        Log.v(TAG, "OnFinishInflate");

        itemImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
        itemTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        itemEstimate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemEstimate);

        super.onFinishInflate();
    }

    public void renderWithEvent(CustomEvent event){
        this.event = event;

        String imageURL = event.imageURL();
        if (imageURL != null){
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageURL).into(itemImage);
        }else{
            itemImage.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        }

        itemTitle.setText(event.title);

        mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        updateEstimate();
    }

    public void updateEstimate(){
        itemEstimate.setText(event.getEstimate());

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateEstimate();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

}
```

And here's the code for the ListView Adapter:

```
private class EventsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            CustomEvent event = (CustomEvent) getItem(position);
            Context context = getActivity();

            CustomViewCell eventItem;
            if (convertView == null){
                eventItem = (CustomViewCell) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cell_event, parent, false);
            }else{
                eventItem = (CustomViewCell) convertView;
            }

            eventItem.renderWithEvent(event);

            return eventItem;
        }

        ...
}
```

Comment: Post your code so that we get some insight.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it was a generic enough question to not post it before. I've added the code for both the custom view, and the list's adapter.

Comment: Also FWIW, I've tried overriding `onDetatchedFromWindow` in the view, but it doesn't seem to get called when it is removed from the `ListView`.

Comment: Don't you have control over what goes into the adapter?  Can't see from the code you are posting but somewhere you must bind the adapter to the list.  And you must do something to put or remove contents to the adapter.

Comment: @PeriHartman Yes, but that's the data side of it. I can't access the actual view object that's being removed to tell it to stop updating very second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're looking for.  Try onDetachedFromWindow().

Comment: I actually tried `onDetatchedFromWindow`, but it only seems to fire when the table itself is also removed. It doesn't fire if a row just is removed.

Comment: It should.  I've used it successfully for exactly what you say.  However, another approach is to add add a reference to each view in your adapter and then call a "destructor" method when you review an element from the adapter.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to go back and try it again. I could've sworn it didn't get called. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
mListView.setRecyclerListener(new AbsListView.RecyclerListener() {
@Override
    public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
  }
});
```

copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26529513/596555