# How to stop autorotating ViewPager listview item?

Tags: android, listview, handler

I have a listview item which contains a ViewPager. The following code is inside a method I created, whose purpose is to allow the ViewPager to autoslide.

However, when the view scrolls off the screen the runnable keeps calling itself and scrolling. In a listview with several of these, these callbacks keeping being called even if it's off the screen.

What's a pattern to keep track of each listview's handler and cancel this when it's no longer on screen? I would also have to reenable when it comes back on screen.

Thanks!

```
    // Inside getView() in my adapter

    if (autoSlide) {

        final int autoSlideDelayMs = 5000;

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        // Attach handler ref to ViewPager so later we can stop this.
        viewPager.setTag(handler);

        final Runnable scrollRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final int currentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                final int itemCount = viewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
                final int itemToShow = currentItem == itemCount - 1 ? 0 : viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1;
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(itemToShow, true);

                if (handler != null) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, autoSlideDelayMs);
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(scrollRunnable, autoSlideDelayMs);
    }
```

I'm also doing the following. This is probably not the best coding practice, but I'm attempting to keep a reference to the handler and make it null when I no longer what the autoslide to occur.

```
    // In my fragment
    listview.setRecyclerListener(new AbsListView.RecyclerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
            final ExtendedViewPager viewPager = (ExtendedViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            if (viewPager != null) {
               Handler h = (Handler)viewPager.getTag();

                if (h != null) {
                    h = null;
                    System.gc();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: this might be helpful but im not sure its exactly what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621225/knowing-when-a-view-in-a-listview-has-gone-off-the-screen

Comment: @TomerShemesh Added some code from your link. It's being called, but the autoslide isn't stopping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opted for using a tag in the View Pager to indicate if the scrolling should continue or not (and not set the Hander as the tag object). So my code is now something like:

In the fragment:

```
/**
 *
 */
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    // Stop any autosliding slideshow listview items
    final int childCount = listview.getChildCount();
    int currentChild = 0;

    while(currentChild < childCount) {
        stopAutoSliding(listview.getChildAt(currentChild++));
    }
}


/**
 * Set a tag to the view pager to indicate autosliding should stop
 */
private void stopAutoSliding(final View view) {
    final View viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setTag(new Object());
    }
}
```

In the adapter:

```
    if (autoSlide) {

        final int autoSlideDelayMs = 5000;

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable scrollRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final int currentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                final int itemCount = viewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
                final int itemToShow = currentItem == itemCount - 1 ? 0 : viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1;
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(itemToShow, true);

                // If the viewPager has a tag, it means we shouldn't keep scrolling.
                final Object continueSliderFlag = viewPager.getTag();

                if (continueSliderFlag == null) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, autoSlideDelayMs);
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(scrollRunnable, autoSlideDelayMs);
    }
```